# Getting a full xml code into variable with php

Tags: php, regex, xml

I need some way to get the full code of a xml file into a variable so i can get what i need with a regex. Example:

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<renderer>
    <positions layout="submission">
        <position name="content">Content</position>
        <position name="media">Media</position>
        <position name="meta">Meta</position>
        <position name="administration">Administration</position>
    </positions>
    <positions layout="edit">
        <position name="content">Content</position>
        <position name="media">Media</position>
        <position name="meta">Meta</position>
        <position name="administration">Administration</position>
    </positions>
</renderer>
```

And i want to get with regex all the content from the "name" tags. This part is not a problem for me, i have the regex for this, i just need to get the full code of the xml.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: How are you trying to obtain the xml? From another php file?

Comment: I try this: `$xml = simplexml_load_file("media/zoo/applications/blog/templates/certificados/renderer/item/positions.xml");`
`$xml = file_get_contents('media/zoo/applications/blog/templates/certificados/renderer/item/positions.xml');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: use a parser like `simplexml` - see around 253 answers here on SO on why and how.

Comment: What do you mean by _all the content from the "name" tags_? What do you mean by _full code of the xml_?

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

```
$xml = file_get_contents('my-xml.txt');
```

(or am I missing something; seems too easy)

Comment: I have try that before, but this returns the values not the full xml structure with tags and everyting.